# как правильно организовать передачу данных между фрагментами в сингл активити приложении

Tags: android, android-fragment

хотелось бы услышать авторитетное мнение
Есть активити, контейнер для фрагментов, и два фрагмента(один сменяет другой по нажатию кнопки)
активити реализует интерфейс для передачи строки между фрагментами

дам код только методов интерфейса, потому что вопрос по ним

один способ закоментирован, другой - нет
Вопрос: возможны ли вообще такие варианты

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
String message = "";
final String KEY = "message";
@Override
public void sendMessage(String message) {
    bundle.putString(KEY,message);

    //Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    //bundle.putString(KEY, message);
    //fragmentManager.setFragmentResult(KEY,bundle);
}
@Override
public String listenMessage() {
    //Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
    //fragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener(KEY, fragment.getViewLifecycleOwner(), new //FragmentResultListener() {
        //@Override
        //public void onFragmentResult(@NonNull String requestKey, @NonNull Bundle result) {
           // message = result.getString(KEY);
        //}
    //});  

//return message;
    return bundle.getString(KEY);
}
```

я так понимаю вариант под комментариями безопаснее, благодаря LifecycleOwner.
 но я явно в
listenMessage() что-то начудил так как у активити нет LifecycleOwner

Comment: Вы немного странное делаете, кажется. Откуда и куда вам надо передать данные? Из фрагмента В в А при закрытии В? Коли так, то должно быть достаточно FragmentResultListener прямо в А использовать, без использования активити.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я хочу чтоб активити был посредником между фрагментами, управлял их взаимодействием. Так ведь строится правильная архитектура?

Comment: нет, не так. Активити - просто площадка для размещения Фрагментов и в их общении не должен учавствовать. уже то, что вы во фрагменте ищете контейнер по ИД - создают массу проблем при переиспользовании.  правильный метод описан в первом комментарии.